# Reverse image of prime ideal is homogeneous prime ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R=k[x_0,...,x_n]$ and $R_j=k[\frac{x_0}{x_j},...,\frac{x_{j-1}}{x_j},\frac{x_{j+1}}{x_j},...,\frac{x_n}{x_j}]$

If $f\in R$, and $f_d,...,f_m$ its homogeneous components and $d,...,m$ their degrees

We can define a map from $R$ to $R_j$ by sending $f$ to  $\frac{f_d}{{x_j}^d}+...+\frac{f_m}{{x_j}^m} $

Now take a prime  ideal $P$ of $R_j$, we know that $P$ must be finitely  generated by $H_1,...,H_r$ polynomials in $R_J$ with degrees of $e_1,...,e_r$ respectively. Then ${x_j}^{e_i}H_i = h_i$ are homogeneous polynomials in $R$

My question is if $φ^{-1}(P)=(h_1,...,h_r)$

The one direction is obvious as $φ(h_i)=H_i$ but I'm having trouble showing the reverse direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "no". Let me illustrate by a trivial example. Choose $n=0$, so you have only one indeterminate in $R$, say $x$, and your map reduces to 
$$\varphi: k[x] \rightarrow k \qquad f\mapsto f(1)$$

and the field $k$ has only one (strict) prime ideal $\{0\}$. But $\varphi^{-1}(0)$ is clearly not just $\{0\}$, because $\varphi(x-1)=0$.

Comment: Thank you quantum. Are you aware of any cases where the result is true? Aside $φ$ being injective

Comment: Any cases of what? what is allowed to be changed and how do you propose $\varphi$ to be injective? Something in your definition of the map should change otherwise it never is injective.

Comment: I mean a case where $φ$ is still not injective. If it were injective the result would be true, but it's not as you've clearly shown. Can it hold If we change something else, or will it fail every time?

Comment: For example, will it fail for $n \ge 1$?

Comment: You can mimick the example in the answer. Just use the $0$ prime ideal of $R_j$ and notice that $x_j-1$ is mapped to $0$. So this will not work also for $n\geq 1$

Comment: Yes but what about the non-zero prime ideals of $R_j$ for $n \ge 1$?